# Smooth Push Slide (Swish Pan) Transition in the VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

is there any way to achieve such a smooth transition between two videos in the VSE, such as the transition that can be seen in the start of this video?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxjNchN189Q&ab_channel=JavierMercedes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular effect looks a bit like the *Transition > Wipe* effect but in the *Wipe* effects it doesn't look like you can move the video, only reveal it with a mask.

You can put your 2 video strips on 2 separate tracks, select the second strip, open the N panel, and keyframe the *Strip > Transform > Position X* to make the image go from right to left:

[image]

If you want to add a kind of motion blur, you can select the strip and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Effect Strip > Gaussian Blur*, which will add a strip over it, then select this effect strip and in the N panel > *Strip > Effect Strip > Size X* keyframe a high value to create some blur, then later in the timeline lower the value down to 0 and keyframe again:

[image]

If you choose to create an *Effect Strip* in order to have the blur effect, you can even create the movement with this strip (N panel > *Strip > Transform*), not with the original strip.

Comment: in the example both videos are moving ... so just a note - aimate Position of both of them or Group them :)

Comment: oh yes you're right, well so he just needs to animate the strip 1 as well, with the same method

Comment: @moonboots I'm a *she* :) Thank you so much again for your fast reply and your informative answer! I think I got a very good result in the end and I am very pleased with it:) I hope that the developers will some day create this effect as a transition preset.

Comment: Thanks also @vklidu for your remark, I did animate also the movement of the first video. Thank you also for your comment!

Comment: @blender28 oh yes I haven't checked the Transition > Wipe

Comment: ok so it doesn't look like you can create this kind of transition with the Transition > Wipe, the images are not moving

Comment: @moonboots I didn't get the same smooth result with the wipe transition interface... I just got a strange result with it. Your way to create this effect works much better in my opinion.

Comment: Wipe doesn't do what you show in your video, also it doesn't seem to work in the latest version (3.1)

Comment: @moonboots I use in the meantime Blender 2.93. Yes I know that the wipe transition doesn't get me the same effect. I hope that in the near future more effects and transitions options will be added to the VSE.

Comment: @blender28 ... you could probably change your nick to "blendher" ;)

Comment: @vklidu Hahah...:)

Answer (score 5):

*I know it is not the transition you asked for, but in some cases it could be easier to handle ...*

If you don't mind - videos stay on place, you can use build-in *Transition* > *Wipe* ... just set *Angle* to 90° and *Blur* to make edge softer.

[image]
Strip selection order matters :)

Comment: Thank you @vklidu for your reply. I did got strange result with the wipe interface. I saw that you wrote that Strip selection order matter, so I tried this again and got somewhat different but decent result, but still I hope there will be some presets for transitions like the one in the link in the video, and more options in the future. Thank you also for your help:)

Comment: We all live in a hope (especially in these days) ...

Comment: Hopefully one day...